# How to set dimensions for 1D convolutional Networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have 2k of observations. Each observation has 2 channels and each channel is a 1D 1024 vector.

```
Observation_dim = (2000,2,1024)
```

Structure:

```
channe1 (1,1024)----> Convolutional layer1---
                                              \
                                               > concatenate-->FCN-->binary_classification     
                                              /   
channe2 (1,1024)----> Convolutional layer2---
```

Each channel contains independent info, so the convolution has to be done 1D and separately for each channel.

This is a binary classification, so each observation can belong to class 0 or 1.

**Problem:** I don't know how to set dimensions for a simple classification ):

**Note:** I'm trying to extract features from each channel separately using a `conv_1d` function then concatenate the flatten output of each `conv_1d` and insert in an FCN.

```
def conv_1d(x):
    w_s=3
    p_s=4
    conv1 = Conv1D(32, w_s, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(x)
    batch1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=p_s)(batch1)

    conv2 = Conv1D(64, w_s, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    batch2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=p_s)(batch2)

    flat = Flatten()(pool2)
    return flat

def tst_1():
    model = Sequential()
    inputs = Input((2, 1024,1))#(batch, height, width, channels)

    x1 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,0])(inputs)
    dense12= conv_1d(x1)

    x2 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,1])(inputs)
    dense22 = conv_1d(x2)


    flat = keras.layers.Concatenate()([dense12, dense22])

    dense1 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(flat)
    BN1 = BatchNormalization()(dense1)
    dense2 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(BN1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
    dense3 = Dense(64, activation='relu')(drop2)
    densef = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense3)

    model = Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = densef)

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


    return model

model = tst_1()
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this using Keras functional API (not the common Sequential way) and here is the result:

```
inputs = Input((2, 1000,1))#(batch, height, width, channels)

# first feature extractor
x1 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,0])(inputs)
conv1 = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(x1)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1)
flat1 = Flatten()(pool1)
# second feature extractor
x2 = Lambda(lambda x:x[:,1])(inputs)
conv2 = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(x2)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv2)
flat2 = Flatten()(pool2)
# merge feature extractors
merge = concatenate([flat1, flat2])
# interpretation layer
hidden1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(merge)
# prediction output
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
```

and the network will look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuQcS.png)

You can find comprehensive info of using Keras API here:
[enter link description here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/keras-functional-api-deep-learning/)